# Python Generating Date Time as Sting with time increments to generate URL

Tags: python, datetime

To Repeatedly call a web URL which has time stamp in the end,
Example URL
'https://mywebApi/StartTime=2019-05-01%2000:00:00&&endTime=2019-05-01%2003:59:59'

> StartTime=2019-05-01%2000:00:00 
>   is URL representation of Time 2019-05-01 00:00:00
>
> endTime=2019-05-01%2003:59:59
>   is URL representation of Time 2019-05-01 00:00:00

Requirement is to make repetitive calls , with 4 hour window.
While adding 4 hours, the date may change, 
Is there a lean way to generate the URL String,
Some thing like

```
baseUrl = 'https://mywebApi/StartTime='
startTime = DateTime(2018-05-03 00:01:00)
terminationTime = DateTime(2019-05-03 00:05:00)
while (startTime < terminationTime):
    endTime = startTime + hours(4)
    url = baseUrl+str(startTime)+"endtime="+str(startTime)
    # request get url
    startTime = startTime + hours(1)
```

Comment: `startTime = datetime(year=2018, month=5, day=3, hour=0, minute=1, second=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datetime.timedelta as well as the strftime function as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
baseUrl = 'https://mywebApi/StartTime='
startTime = datetime(year=2018, month=5, day=3, hour=0, minute=1, second=0)
terminationTime = datetime(year=2018, month=5, day=3, hour=3, minute=59, second=59)
while (startTime < terminationTime):
    endTime = startTime + timedelta(hours=4)
    url = baseUrl + startTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S") + "endtime=" + endtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S")
    # request get url
    startTime = endTime
```

The following link is useful https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html or you can look at the official datetime documentation.

edit: using what u/John Gordan said to declare the initial dates